# How can I fix touch lag in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, activex, multi-touch, lag

I've encountered strange behavior when using AS3's `TouchEvent`s to handle multi-touch. The touch lags considerably in certain situations, but Flash's frame rate isn't affected. It's as though the touches are getting buffered and the events just aren't dispatched until several seconds after the touch.

I've uploaded a demonstration here: https://youtu.be/omkCDqljfio

I've only managed to reproduce this touch lag in the ActiveX version of Flash Player, but I've reproduced it in both Windows 10 and Windows 7. So what I have here is a C# application that's hosting my AS3 test suite, but it can also be observed if the swf is viewed in Internet Explorer.

Since my application already involves hosting the SWF in a WPF window, I've been attempting to create a solution where touch is received in C# and then communicated to the AS3. It would work perfectly but it seems my WPF window isn't receiving touch frames when the touch is on a `WindowsFormsHost`. So there's another problem that I have to solve.

FlashDevelop project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxC2eCzurT9rd0gzSGc4TUdQLTQ/view
Visual Studio solution: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxC2eCzurT9rUThmRHBKWHZmbzA/view

AS3 touch events:

```
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

        stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, stage_touchBegin);
        stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, stage_touchMove);
        stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, stage_touchEnd);
```

Creating the display objects that contribute to the lag, presumably because of the touch event capture phases:

```
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 500; i++) 
        {
            Dotter.createBGDot(_bgLayer, _shapesOn ? Shape : Sprite);
        }
```

...

```
    static public function createBGDot(bgLayer:Sprite, dotClass:Class):void 
    {
        var dot:* = new dotClass();
        var color:Color = new Color();
        color.brightness = Math.random();
        dot.graphics.beginFill(color.color);
        dot.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, Math.random() * 400 + 40);
        dot.x = Math.random() * bgLayer.stage.stageWidth;
        dot.y = Math.random() * bgLayer.stage.stageHeight;
        bgLayer.addChild(dot);
    }
```

I know this is sort of an unusual situation, but I appreciate any advice about how to resolve these issues.

Comment: I've inherited an old project. Remaking the whole thing would be more costly than it's worth. Also, Flash is a good platform. Companies have moved away from Flash because support for Flash Player has waned, but I don't think Flash deserves a bad reputation. What would you suggest as an alternative for 2D vector animations?

Comment: If people are voting to close this question, I'd certainly appreciate it if they could say how I should look for help instead. I've worked hard on presenting the information about this issue.

Comment: The problem is that this question is too broad as it would require a lot of time to debug the various part. It wouldn't be so broad if you could at least show the most relevant part of the code, but I doubt that you have identified it.

Comment: All right, that sounds fair.

Comment: How long exactly is the lag?  or does it vary everytime?  is it the TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN event that is lagging, or one of the others you are listening to?   What does "certain situations" mean exactly?

Comment: It's explained in the video. The lag occurs only when the Flash display list is populated, which seems to imply that the lag is related to the touch event phases: capture, targeting, and bubbling. And for whatever reason, the lag seems to really trigger when the touches are around the edges of the screen. The length of the lag varies, but it's often several seconds.

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't the GUI? Is it at all possible to test it in Adobe Scout to see what functions are causing the most issues?

Comment: If Flash was having issues with rendering then surely that would be reflected in the frame rate, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I've used Adobe Scout I think it is a rendering issue after all. The frame rate still shows 30fps because the processing time just barely manages to hit the 30fps mark. Lowering the frame rate fixes the problem.

It is still strange that the touch events would have such a long delay when the frame rate is just barely falling short, though.